# Tizen gyroscope sample rate: who is limiting it?

Tags: w3c, tizen

I am looking at developing an application on the Tizen platform and want to incorporate a gyroscope along with the accelerometer.  The accelerometer has a reasonable sample rate but the gyroscope seems to be around 1Hz.  The [documentation](http://w3c.github.io/deviceorientation/spec-source-orientation.html) that I have found points to the gyroscope being used mainly for device [orientation](https://developer.tizen.org/community/tip-tech/obtaining-device-orientation-and-acceleration-using-built-sensors). The low sample rates make sense for orientation, but the gyroscope has plenty of other applications. Who is limiting the gyroscope to such a low sample rate? Is it Tizen, the W3C, or would sample rates be up to the device manufactures(for example, Samsung)?

Comment: On which device are you trying to develop the app- Samsung Z1 or Gear S?

Comment: @srkushwaha Is there much of a difference in what the API exposes?  I had wearable devices in mind, but I assume my concerns are still valid for either.

Comment: Nope there will not be much difference in APIs exposed. But gyroscope sensor not available on Samsung Z1.